# shell script reading variables from a shell script

Tags: shell

How to take the variable like this?

**a.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
./b.sh
echo "The message is: $MESSAGE"
```

**b.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
MESSAGE="hello"
```

Then run:

```
$ ./a.sh
The message is:
```

I want to take the value of variable MESSAGE in a.sh

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `. ./b.sh` (or `source b.sh` depending on your shell flavor) it will run b in the same shell as a rather than starting a different process.